# cmake target_link_libraries silently not insert item to target

Tags: cmake

I use the following CMake commands to create a library B:

```
find_package(A REQUIRED)

add_library(B SHARED a.c b.c)

target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A::alib)
```

Then I link the B in another lib:

```
target_link_libraries(C PUBLIC B)
```

When linking final executable with `C` giving *ldd* I see that although `A::alib` is in, lib `B` is not.
How can this be done?

I'm giving some details of development ( Tsyvarev thanks a lot)
The `target_link_libraries(C PUBLIC B)` is in a separate CMakeLists.txt file. In an Outer directory which includes the directory with `target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A::alib)` CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Weird. It seems that in the line `target_link_libraries(C PUBLIC B )` target `B` means **different thing**, than in the `add_library( B SHARED a.c b.c)` line. Do you create `C` library in the **separate** `CMakeLists.txt`? Please, describe (int the question post) hierarchy between `CMakeLists.txt` scripts involved into the problem.

Comment: "Outer directory which includes the directory with `target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A::alib)` CMakeLists.txt." - Well, this seems reasonable. Still, the problem itself is ..strange. Please, provide [mcve], so we could reproduce your problem by ourselves.